# Docker Solr can't load the core I have transferred from other solr

Tags: docker, solr

These are the problems. 
[image: SolrUI]

[image: Docker]

The image from docker were transferred from other solr.
They were transferred while the container solr was running. 
I can't restart the container solr because when I do, the files that I transferred will be deleted. How can I load the cores I transferred from other solr on this solr container?

I figured out that I just need to start the container after restarting the solr so that the cores I transferred will not get deleted. 
But I encountered this problem, please help me.

[SolrError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22PJJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding you have already copied the core from one solr to another, but its not loading. So you should run the solr command inside the new solr container as given below.

```
 solr create_core -c <<core-name>> -d <<path-of-the-core-folder>>
```

You will get successful message as

Created new core "core-name"

Comment: Thanks for the response. It says the core already exists. So your were trying to say that I'm gonna need to create a new core? I just need to load the core I transferred from other solr.

Comment: what is the response of "curl http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=STATUS" from inside the container..?

Comment: {
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0},
  "initFailures":{
    "core_invoke_monitor":"org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: /opt/solr/server/solr/cores/core_invoke_monitor/data/index/write.lock",
    "core_tracker":"org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /opt/solr/server/solr/cores/core_tracker/data"},
  "status":{}}

Comment: Hi Prem, I figured out that I just need to start the container after restarting the solr so that the cores I transferred will not get deleted. But I encountered a new problem. Kindly check the image above.

Comment: we should find using trial and error method. Please try one thing move both the core folders to tmp folder and run "solr create_core -c <<core-name>> -d <<path-of-the-core-folder>>"

Comment: I fixed it, anyways, thanks for your help. I created again a new core, I figured out that I forgot to add the port that I am using on firewall that's why the cores were not working before.